# how can we import csv file into mysql but the name column having "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris" . while import the name split into two columns

Tags: python, mysql, xampp

[**csv image Name column having comma. after import it showing both seperate names but I need name should be in single column **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZW1Q.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Show your CSV as text, not as Excel-like parsed output. *while import the name split into two columns* Edit your CSV and alter the columns delimiting symbol with one which does not occur in the values. `;`, `$`, `#`, <Tab>...

Comment: you can separate your CSV values by semicolon (`;`), by the way, use the post title for a short summary of your problem and write the whole problem in the post body, also, you don´t need to link images, you can post images in the description.